# Prevent posts from being published unless a taxonomy is selected

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I've created a custom taxonomy in WordPress. I want to prevent posts from being published *unless* a taxonomy is selected. What hook do I need to use to do that? I want to use only php hooks, not jQuery.

**Code to create the taxonomy:**

```
function sport_type_st_t(){ 
    /*** =========== Sport type ================== ***/
    $argsT=array( 
         'labels'=>array( 'name'=>__('Sport Types'), 
                          'singular_name'=>__('Sport Type'), 
                          'all_items'=>__('All Sport Type'), 
                          'search_items'=>__('Search Sport Type'), 
                          'edit_item'=>__('Edit Sport Type'), 
                          'view_item'=>__('View Sport Type'), 
                          'update_item'=>__('Update Sport Type'), 
                          'add_new_item'=>__('Add Sport Type'), 
                          'new_item_name'=>__('New Sport Type'), ), 
                          'hierarchical' => true, 'public'=>true, ); 

    register_taxonomy( 'sport_type_st_t', array('post'), $argsT ); //add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'wpse_73006_submenu_order' ); 
    }

add_action('init','sport_type_st_t',20.1);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to only allow a post to be published if it has at least one taxonomy selected? That's covered here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/dont-publish-custom-post-type-post-if-a-meta-data-field-isnt-valid/15627#15627

Comment: Now, I just want to Prevent post from being published if some condition is not satisfied.As above   if($val==0){
            //  I want to Prevent post from being published
        }

Comment: ...isn't that the same thing?

Comment: I want to achieve this using PHP. I don't want to use Jquery

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question to reflect that,

Comment: Great. Can you please provide me some solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93163/discussion-between-user5320720-and-bfdatabaseadmin).